Getting this error : Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
This is my code:
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const adminRouter = require("./routes/admin.js");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user.js");

// Middleware for parsing request bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//app.use new way, it tells that any request comes to /admin/anything*** to to adminRouter, similar way any request to /user/anything ->> go to userRouter
app.use("/admin",adminRouter);
app.use("/user", userRouter);

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

If I am using a callback like this:
app.use("/admin",()=>adminRouter);
app.use("/user", ()=>userRouter);

it worked!
Can someone explain this?

Can you share your adminRouter and/or userRouter?

The error you’re encountering occurs because Router.use() expects a middleware function (or chain of middleware functions), but the way you've imported or defined your adminRouter and userRouter is causing it to behave like an object instead of a middleware function.
app.use("/admin", adminRouter):
adminRouter must be a middleware function (usually created by express.Router()). If adminRouter is not defined as a valid middleware (but instead is an object or something else), you'll get the error: "Router.use() requires a middleware function but got an Object".
app.use("/admin", () => adminRouter):
Here, you're passing a callback function that returns adminRouter. This works, but not in the way you might think. It bypasses the middleware chain because you're technically using a function that does nothing with the request/response. This is not the correct approach.
your admin.js and user.js files should look like this:
admin.js:


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Define routes for /admin
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Admin Home");
});

module.exports = router;



user.js


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Define routes for /user
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("User Home");
});

module.exports = router;



If adminRouter and userRouter are properly exported as router objects (middleware functions), your original code should work


const adminRouter = require("./routes/admin.js");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user.js");

// Attach routers
app.use("/admin", adminRouter);
app.use("/user", userRouter);



